# Do I pay more tax when 2 extra payments are in this paypacket

Tags: income-tax, united-kingdom

I recently worked about 17 hours of overtime in a weekend, submitted it and expected to be paid that month but I missed the cut off date apparently.

This is fine, but I will also be paid part of my bonus next month, so both the overtime, and the bonus will be in the same pay packet. Does this mean I will pay more tax/NI over all, or just more at once?

Some example figures to work with in case it helps:

- Say I earn £2200 a month before tax, £1800ish after.
- The OT is about £500, and bonus is about £700.

Comment: You should check your paycheck whether the bonus & OT already deducted from tax.

Comment: The bonus & OT is always before tax unfortunately

Answer (score 11, accepted):

With a basic salary of £2,200 per month, anything extra will always be taxed at the basic rate or higher. But if you earn £3,400 in one month, that’s an annualised amount of £40,800, still well below the £50,000 higher-rate threshold, so there should be no risk of any of it being taxed at higher rate. Your National Insurance will also be the same, because you won’t go above the weekly threshold of £962 where the rate *drops*, but you’re always above the £166 weekly threshold for paying NI at all. So you should end up paying exactly the same PAYE tax and NI as you would have done if the extra payments were in two different months. (Note that even if you did end up paying more tax, you should get it back eventually, unless the payments would have been in two different tax years before one was delayed.)

Comment: Amazing, thank you. I was thinking this to be true but just wanted to check!

Answer (score 0):

Having lots of money lumped into one pay period rather than spread over several can cause more tax to be *withheld*, but should not increase the tax *liability* (which is how much you need to pay overall). So if, at the end of the year, you have more withheld then the tax due on your income, you should get that back as a refund

Comment: It's quite rare even for it to cause more tax to be withheld in the UK, because withholding is calculated cumulatively and is designed to match liability for most people.